# Filter for the Numbers Following a String on a Webpage With a Python Web Scraper

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to filter for the total number of followers between all stories on an account. I've managed to do all the basics and put everything needed in the 'header' variable, I just need to filter out everything except the number following "Follows:" but can't find how to do that. Any help is appreciated.

(Yes, I know I have a lot of imports I don't need, this project was kind of slapped together and I copied the imports from another Webscraping project I'm working on)

Edit: The end goal is to add all of the follows together

```
import bs4
import sys
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/Curious Beats/Downloads/chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("https://www.fictionpress.com/u/541077/Imperfect-Princess")


page_html = driver.page_source
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

list_header = []
header = page_soup.find_all("div",{"class":"z-padtop2 xgray"})
for items in header:
        try:
            list_header.append(items.get_text())
        except:
            continue

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What happens?

You try to `find_all()` the header info with multiple class names, what wont work this way:

```
find_all("div",{"class":"z-padtop2 xgray"})
```

### How to fix that?

Use the css selector, think it is much easier to chain the classes this way:

```
soup.select('div.z-padtop2.xgray')
```

### How to get the number of follows?

If you do not wanna use `regex` just `split()` the text and select the value by `.index('Follows:')+1`

```
follows = items.get_text().split()
list_header.append(follows[follows.index('Follows:')+1])
```

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
url = "https://www.fictionpress.com/u/541077/Imperfect-Princess"

driver.get(url)
sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")


list_header = []
header = soup.select('div.z-padtop2.xgray')
for items in header:
        try:
            follows = items.get_text().split()
            list_header.append(follows[follows.index('Follows:')+1])
        except:
            list_header.append('no follows')
            continue

driver.quit()
list_header
```

**Output**

```
['1,174',
 '364',
 '1,965',
 '34',
 '61',
 '215',
 '18',
 '859',
 '320',
 '1,483',
 '224',
 '196',
 '68',
 '57',
 '12',
 '208',
 '31',
 '33',
 '25',
 '7',
 'no follows',
 '20',
 '26',
 '6',
 '31']
```

Comment: Definitely got it all in a list, the only problem is that it also pulls follows from the 'favorites' page, as it seems to use the same div tag. Any idea how I'd isolate just their own stories?

Comment: Would recommend to ask a new question for that, if you tried and stuck, cause solution would change a bit - Hint: you should append `dicts` to your `list` that contains more info `{'title':'some title, 'follows':1234}, {...} so you can differentiate the follows later.